# NPM dead after update - cannot find module (OSX)

Tags: node.js, npm, osx-elcapitan

Just did a minor `npm` update to the latest version (I can't remember what it was as `npm` no longer works - hence the question) but I think my installed version before the update was 5.6.0. That could be wrong though.

Anyway after running...

```
sudo npm install -g npm
```

... `npm` no longer works at all. Anything I do results in :

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:596
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './auth.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:594:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/index.js:7:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

After trying a few different things including reinstalling node via brew the only thing that worked was to download and run the node installer binary from the [node site](https://nodejs.org/en/).

Hope it helps somebody else.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue this way:

```
yarn global add npm
```